# Crosswalkプラグイン利用時、サーバ通信ができない

Tags: monaca, cordova

お世話になります。

monacaで、Crosswalkプラグインを入れた状態で、
サーバと通信すると、下記エラーが出てしまいました。

（できれば）サーバ側で何も設定すること無く、
正常に通信をする方法はありますでしょうか。

===[エラー内容]===
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxx.xxx.jp/xxxx.php/xxxxx . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

残念ながら、Crosswalkプラグインの仕様上、サーバー側に

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: file://
```

や

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

の設定がないと、このエラーが出てしまうと思います。
ビルドしたアプリでは、アプリのコード領域にindex.htmlがあるのでこのエラーが出ない
のですが、Monacaデバッガーでは書き換え可能なファイル領域にindex.htmlがあるため、
このエラーを避けられません。

この問題を解決するには、Crosswalkプラグイン側を改修する必要があります。試しに改修
したものを
https://github.com/knight9999/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
に用意しました。標準のCrosswalkプラグインを外して、こちらのプラグインを組み込み、
カスタムビルド版デバッガーを作成すれば、カスタムビルド版デバッガー上ではエラーが出ず
にサーバー通信を行うことが出来るようになります。

また、この改修は何らかの形で、次期Monacaデバッガー(6.0.x系)に取り込む予定です。